# Issue with date format output in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, nls

I have a requirement where I have to insert date fields into a varchar column. I am directly inserting the record into the table without any typecast. In one environment it's inserting as 29-AUG-16, and in the other environment it's storing as 29-08-2016. Hence, my subsequent processing of the data is getting failed. I am expecting data as DD-MON-RR in both environment. In both environment nls format is DD-MON-RR in the nls session parameters table. What is the reason for the difference in two environment?
I tried typecast using TO_CHAR(DATECOL, 'DD-MON-RR' ) But still data is inserted as dd-mm-yyyy format

Comment: "a requirement to insert date fields into a varchar column". Just wondering, why?

Comment: Because we create a primary key using date and concatenate with other key fields.

Comment: You're creating an extra column with concatenated values from other columns - and making that the primary key; rather than having a compound primary key across the original columns? Seems a bit odd... Anyway, you shouldn't rely on NLS settings, and how you actually perform the insert might be ignoring them anyway - where you are getting the date value from, for instance (it may be a string earlier than you think?), and what binding or explicit/implicit conversion is happening.

Comment: Please include your full insert statement, along with the DDL for the table(s), or at least the actual data types of the columns and any variables you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [TO_CHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) function to convert date into character and insert it into varchar column.

Instead of simply writing date_column , you should use something like this in your insert query

`INSERT INTO date_tab VALUES(TO_CHAR(date_col, 'DD-MON-YY'))`

Answer (score 0):

NLS values are set per session depending on server defaults, client defaults and explicit session settings. So if you want a standard format for all sessions you have to set desired NLS at operation level to override all possible (almost unpredictible) NLS resulting combinations. In `to_char` function you should set the third parameter (NLS) to your selected NLS date format.

Comment: I tried inserting using TO_CHAR(DATECOL, 'DD-MON-RR'). However, still value is inserted as mm-dd-yyyy format for unknown reason

Comment: Try third parameter `to_char(datecol, 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=english')`. On another side, I wonder if there is a trigger involved.

Comment: Thanks. But it didn't help and there is no trigger involved. The query I working fine in Dev but not in higher environment

Comment: It is close to impossible for a value to be inserted as mm-dd-yyyy if you use an explicit TO_CHAR(datecol, 'DD-MON-RR'). You should double-check your code. In particular, make sure not to use TO_DATE mistakenly or use a wrong column type at source or target.